# Page not found error shown while installing wordpress on IIS server

Tags: installation, iis

I am installing a wordpress folder on a windows server, but it shows page not found. I am unable to even see the first page of installation. This is the site address http://np-environmental.com/newsite/

Can anyone tell what the issue can be??

Comment: Have you uploaded all the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've uploaded all the Wordpress files, then it appears your web site isn't setup to process .php files. **Ask your web host to enable PHP for your site.**

It would appear you've uploaded the files, as I see http://np-environmental.com/newsite/license.txt and /readme.html, and looking deeper /newsite/wp-admin/css/about.css

Assuming the Windows server has PHP installed and configured, and IIS is setup to process PHP requests in general, your site will need to have a handler mapping for PHP added. Otherwise you'll get `HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found` if you try opening any .php files.

If this is your own Windows server, there are detailed instructions on what you need to do for IIS 7+ at http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php, or older IIS 5.1/6 at http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis6.php.